# Lost File Recovery Assistance Request for VSCode Editor

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am having trouble saving files in the VSCode editor and would appreciate some assistance. Let me explain the situation:

Normally, I open .ipynb files without opening the folder they belong to. I make sure to save the file before shutting down my computer. However, today I opened both the folder and the file at the same time. As a result, I was prompted to overwrite the file due to differences between the new and old versions. Unfortunately, I was not expecting VSCode to overwrite the old file with the new one.

I tried to check the history, but it only goes back to April and today is in the middle of June. I do not know how to retrieve or restore my file. The code I had been working on took an entire day to build, so this situation is quite distressing.

How can I recover my file?

Comment: "_I tried to check the history, but it only goes back to April and today is in the middle of June._" so? I thought you only made the change today?

Comment: @starball no I have work frequently on that file, I have googled but don’t know where to find the temporary file because it’s not in the history of my file in VSCode

Comment: when you say "history of my file", are you referring to VS Code's "Local History" feature?

Comment: @starball yah right, in VSCode, we have the "Local History" feature to store the history version of our file